# Python all()/any() like method for a portion/part of list?

Tags: python, loops, for-in-loop

What would be the most elegant/pythonic way of achieving: "if x% of total values in a list are greater than the y, return true". I have currently implemented a function:

```
def check(listItems, val):
   '''A method to check all elements of a list against a given value.
   Returns true if all items of list are greater than value.'''
   return all(x>val for x in listItems)
```

But for my use case, waiting for this particular condition is quite costly and somewhat useless. I would want to proceed if ~80% of the items in list are greater than the given value.
One approach in my mind is to sort the list in descending order, create another list and copy 80% of the elements of list to the new list, and run the function for that new list. However, I am hoping that there must be a more elegant way of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you do any ranking, you'll immediately get hit by an `nlog(n)` complexity. Instead, iterate on each element in a loop like you are doing (linear time), check how many is greater than `val`, and then do your 80% check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are dealing with long lists which is why this is costly. If would be nice if you could exit early as soon as a condition is met. `any()` will do this, but you'll want to avoid reading the whole list before passing it to `any()`. One options might be to use `itertools.accumulate` to keep a running total of `True` values and the pass that to any. Something like:

```
from itertools import accumulate

a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1]

# true if 50% are greater than 1
goal = .5 * len(a) # at least 5 out of 10   
any( x > goal for x in accumulate(n > 1 for n in a))
```

`accumulate` won't need to read the whole list — it will just start passing the number of True values seen up to that point. `any` should short-circuit as soon as it finds a true value, which in the above case is at index 5.

Comment: Thanks a bunch (y)

Comment: Great answer! Although if you use map vs comprehensions *(although less readable)* it is faster see my answer.

Comment: Is there any way of performing the optimization in my answer using `accumulate`? (If it will be impossible to meet the goal then stop early)

Comment: Hey @ZevChonoles, yeah, I bet you could. You can pass the `accumulate()` to `enumerate` which will give you tuples of `(index, number_true_so_far)` like `for index, number_true in enumerate(accumulate(n > val for n in a)):` Then you wouldn't need the first test or counter, but the rest of the logic should work. It's a nice idea IMO.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
def check(listItems, val, threshold=0.8):
    return sum(x > val for x in listItems) > len(listItems) * threshold
```

It states: `check` is `True` if more than `threshold`% (0.80 by default) of the elements in `listItems` are greater than `val`.

Comment: This approach is great as it doesnt require any extra libraries, which means it would work for python 2 as well (more generic solution). Thank you (y)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` for this. By far this is the fastest method. Refer to my other answer as this is faster than the methods in that.

```
def check(listItems, val, goal=0.8):
    return len((*filter(val.__lt__, listItems),)) >= len(listItems) * goal
```

Tested result time for this ran along with the methods in my other question is:

```
1.684135717988247
```

Answer (score 1):

Check each item in order.

- If you reach a point where you are satisfied then return True early.
- If you reach a point where you can never be satisfied, even if every future item passes the test, then return False early.
- Otherwise keep going (in case the later elements help you satisfy the requirement).

This is the same idea as FatihAkici in the comments above, but with a further optimization.

```
def check(list_items, ratio, val):
    passing = 0
    satisfied = ratio * len(list_items)
    for index, item in enumerate(list_items):
        if item > val:
            passing += 1
        if passing >= satisfied:
            return True
        remaining_items = len(list_items) - index - 1
        if passing + remaining_items < satisfied:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t want to take credit for Mark Meyer’s answer as he came up with the concept of using accumulate and any as well as theirs being more pythonic/readable, but if you’re looking for the "fastest" approach then modifying his approach with using `map` vs using comprehensions is faster.

```
any(map(goal.__le__, accumulate(map(val.__lt__, listItems))))
```

Just to test:

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import accumulate

def check1(listItems, val):
    goal = len(listItems)*0.8
    return any(x > goal for x in accumulate(n > val for n in listItems))

def check2(listItems, val):
    goal = len(listItems)*0.8
    return any(map(goal.__le__, accumulate(map(val.__lt__, listItems))))

items = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1]

for t in (check1, check2):
    print(timeit(lambda: t(items, 1)))
```

The results are:

```
3.2596251670038328
2.0594907909980975
```